# Arduino as Slave on I2C bus to read data from other I2C devices

Tags: i2c

Good afternoon;
I am a bit new to the world of I2C bus. I'm trying to implement a project that have  Arduino MEGA as a master and Arduino nano as slave. I have some I2C sensors that i want the slave (Arduino nano) to read. Please how can i implement this.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that your I2C slave Nano should also be a master for the I2C sensors?

Comment: A uC having only one hardware i2c interface can only be master OR slave, not both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand now. I'm thinking the best approach will be to use other pins of the Arduino Nano to interface the I2C sensors. But because these sensors are I2C sensors, i believe they will not just work directly with other pins except the dedicated I2C pins. Do you know how i can enable other pins of the Arduino Nano to be used for the I2C sensors?

Answer (score 0):

An Arduino can be both a master and a slave.  Nick Gammon's page on I2C describes how to do it.   http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c

> Communicating with other devices
>
> So all this I2C stuff is great, you can use just two wires (plus ground) to talk to up to 119 devices. But what if you have a device (like a keypad) that doesn't support I2C? Well, the simple answer is that you can use something that does as an interface. For example, a second Arduino. My examples above do just that, using one as the master and second one to display text on LEDs.
>
> In fact, the "master" can also act as a slave, since you can have multiple masters on one wire. The example below shows how you can send data from one Arduino to another, whilst waiting for information to be sent from the second back to the first.

See the link for code examples.

Comment: Does the `Wire` now support bus arbitration, so that multi master can be done without locking the bus?

Comment: No idea, I've rarely used I2C, preferring instead the much faster SPI.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have seen what he did and it was great. However because my sensors are I2C sensors, it may not work well as he did.  I'm thinking the best approach will be to use other pins of the Arduino Nano to interface the I2C sensors. But because these sensors are I2C sensors, i believe they will not just work directly with other pins except the dedicated I2C pins. Do you know how i can enable other pins of the Arduino Nano to be used for the I2C sensors?

Comment: What are your sensors? Part numbers?

Comment: Proximity sensor, VCNL4040, Time of Flight Sensor VL6180

Comment: "VCNL4040 applies single slave address 0x60 (HEX) of 7-bit addressing following I2C protocol. "   "The VL6180X is controlled over an I2C interface. The default I2C address is 0x29 (7-bit). "  So, two different addresses. Connect both to SDA & SCL, talk to one, then talk to the other.